# How to use msg.payload globally for MQTT Python client?

Tags: python, mqtt

I want to ask if there's a way to use `msg.payload` globally instead of just within the callback function.

Bellow is the basic callback function:

```
# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
    # I usually then specify my steps here, but how can I use the variable outside?


client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
```

For example, I want to do something like this:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
    return msg.payload

global_data= on_message
# do whatever I want with the data. I already tried to do this but it didn't work because 
# the client loops forever using client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: What do you mean? The message only exists inside the callback. If you need it anywhere else, you need to pass it there.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I pass it?

Comment: Same way as any other function parameter. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: You can just show me in answer and if it worked for me then I will gladly accept your answer. I just don't know how :/

Comment: I can't, because I have no idea what you are trying to do or where you are having problems.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to pass it. I will edit the question

Comment: But as I said, *this makes no sense*. Why would you want to do this globally? The message is not a global thing, it's something that happens at a particular time, and is passed to the callback. It just doesn't exist at the point where the global namespace is evaluated. You need to do your actions *within* on_message, and that can include calling other functions from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `client.start_loop` function instead of the `client.loop` function. This will start the network loop on a separate thread allowing you to do your own thing on the main thread.

You can then set or change the value of a global variable to the content of the `msg.payload` from within the callback.

E.g.

```
global_var

def on_message(client, userdata, msg): 
  global global_var
  print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
  global_var = msg.payload
```